# Accepting bids with custom controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails 3.2 project.
There are a bid object and i want the user to be able to accept this bid!
How can i do this?
My first thought is about to make a new method on bids controller and in the method i have to update the accept boolean of bid.Something like that?

```
  def accept
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
    @bid.subject ='accept!!!!'
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed post."
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to "/mybids" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're question is a little vague, because it's not clear what a `bid` is attached to, or what the other models are in your app, since you don't say.

However, let's say that this is an auction site, and auctions have bids. When a bid is accepted

- All other bids on that auction are destroyed
- The bid that was accepted has it's `accepted` boolean field set to `true`.

If that is close to what you're trying to do, then the code below should accomplish that.

in `app/controllers/bids_controller.rb`

```
# PUT /bids/:id/accept
def BidsController < ApplicationController
  def accept
    @bid = Bid.find(params[:id])
    @bid.update_attribute(:accepted, true)
    @bid.auction.bids.each do |rejected_bid|
      rejected_bid.destroy unless rejected_bid == @bid   # destroys all be the accepted bid
    end

    flash[:notice] = "Bid accepted."
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to "/mybids" }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Then you need to add a route for this action to your `config/routes.rb` file. Something like...

```
resources :bids do
  put :accept, :on => :member
end
```

Form the view, you would link to this route like this:

```
link_to "accept", accept_bid_path(@bid)
```

And if you call `rake routes` from your command line, you should see an entry that looks like this:

```
accept_bid PUT   /bids/:id/accept(.format)    {:action=>"accept", :controller=>"bids}
```

Comment: Yes!this is what i want to do!And how can i call it from the view??

Comment: You have to add a route for the custom action. Then it would be available as a helper, and would be `accept_bid_path(:id)` where `:id` is the **id** of the `Bid` object you're accepting.

Comment: I added the route definition to the answer as well. Should be all the info you need. For more info, you'll want to see this routing guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html